# How can the code refer SQLPATH correctly written in config file with python and flask?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy

Im writing test code with pytest for testing API written with python3. 
The problem is that the code cannot access to sql_path but the path correctly is set in config file.

> Which point should I check on the below code ? Although the error
>   message showed 'KeyError', correct key is already set.

*I already tried to check `print(sql_path_dict.get('get_token'))` and it returned 'None'.

error message

```
   if token_type != TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER:
            return 2, client

        token = secret


        print(sql_path_dict.get('get_token'))
>       sql_path = sql_path_dict['get_token']
E       KeyError: 'get_token'

../xxx/xxx/auth/auth.py:126: KeyError
```

config file

```
SQL_PATH = {
    'get_token': "../xxx/xxx/xxx/auth/auth.get_token.sql",
}
```

python3

```
import base64
import datetime
from flask import abort
from flask import jsonify

import uuid
import logging
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
sql_path_dict = {}
...
...

dba = None
logger = None


def init_app(app, db, log):
    global sql_path_dict
    sql_path_dict = app.config['SQL_PATH']
    app.config.setdefault('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS', False)
    db.init_app(app)

    global dba
    dba = db

    global logger
    logger = log

...
...
...


def access(request):
   request_check = 0
    client = "0"
    token_type, input_client_id, secret = get_secret(request, request_check)

    if token_type != TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER:
        return 2, client

    access_token = secret

    print(sql_path_dict.get('get_token'))
    sql_path = sql_path_dict['get_token']
...
...
...
```

Comment: what is app.config? what is app? Did you import settings in the same way in the test? Seeing a test fail because it doesn't have a db token suggests that it may be too heavy to be a "unit test". Have you considered mocking the entire database?

Comment: what is app.config? > app.config file is the above code on this post (config file). what is app? > app is this flask application. Did you import settings in the same way in the test? > Yes. Have you considered mocking the entire database? > What is the exact meaning of this question ? You mean that mock can create temporary the entire database including table schemas and data ? How can be possible it to mock the entire database ? Im still kinda beginner and this application is not using ORM.

Comment: a mock db connection might not be attached to a real db. The tag said unit test, but don't worry about it if that's not the kind of testing you're doing. Is this question about global variables set in one place but not accessible in another?

Comment: This is a part of code for unit testing. Why did you think so 'Is this question about global variables set in one place but not accessible in another' ? Because I did not assume it. I'm curious of the reason behind this question. It might be hint for this problem.